# Some keyboards work, others don't?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I have a gaming keyboard - a Redragon Elite S101. For some reason, after booting up my PC as usual, the keyboard was completely unresponsive and no key strokes register with the computer. The Num Lock light is also on, but when I press the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> button, the light wont toggle, and the same is true for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

To my surprise, other key boards work on my PC, and my S101 works perfectly on other computers too.

I've tried reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all`, I've looked in Universal Access, I've tried messing with `fwupd`, and I've even tried different USB ports. Unfortunately, none of these have worked. Any ideas? Or should I just get a new keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please (with a working keyboard already connected) connect the problematic keyboard, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `lsusb` and [edit] your question to include the output of the previous command? You can copy and paste the terminal content into the question body. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a reddragon keyboard and it requires a special driver called "aziokbd" By swoogan on bitbucket. I'm not sure if you would need the same.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to go about this driver. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)